# Compute shader link failure on Intel HD 4xxx / 5xxx GPUs

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

The following compute shader is causing troubles on Intels HD 4xxx / 5xxx series GPUs, using an OpenGL 4.3 Core context.

It compiles, but then fails to link with an absolutely useless error message:

> SHADER_ID_LINK error has been generated. GLSL link failed for program 4, "": Out of resource error.

As far as I understand this shader should be completely legal on a GPU which claims to be OpenGL 4.3 compliant, and it does in fact work on newer GPUs just fine.

Seen the error happening on 20.19.15.5126 and a number of different, all up-to-date driver versions. OS Windows 8 and Windows 10, 64bit variants.

```
#version 430 core

// DO NOT CHANGE, must match game internal layout
struct TileData {
    // TF_ flags 0:32
    uint flags;
    // TF_ flags 32:64
    uint flags2;

    // Sprites are all:
    // spriteID=0:16, spriteFlags=16:32
    uint floorSpriteUID ;
    uint wallSpriteUID;
    
    uint itemSpriteUID;
    uint creatureSpriteUID;

    uint jobSpriteFloorUID;
    uint jobSpriteWallUID;

    // fluidLevel=0:8, lightLevel=0:8, vegetationLevel=8:16
    uint packedLevels;
};

struct TileDataUpdate {
    uint id;
    TileData tile;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) writeonly restrict buffer tileData1
{
    TileData data[];
} tileData;

layout(std430, binding = 1) readonly restrict buffer tileDataUpdate1
{
    TileDataUpdate data[];
} tileDataUpdate;

uniform int uUpdateSize;

layout(local_size_x = 64) in;

void main()
{
    uint id = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
    if(id < uUpdateSize)
    {
        TileDataUpdate data = tileDataUpdate.data[id];
        tileData.data[data.id] = data.tile;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what could possibly be the cause for the link error? I don't have access to any such GPU myself, so I'm unable to test that by myself.

EDIT:
Testing with a 5 years old driver version (20.19.15.4624) it does actually work out of the box. So this is (yet another) regression in Intels drivers. Still clueless what exactly is triggering the bug or how to work around it.

Comment: OS?  Driver version?  [mcve]?

Comment: @genpfault Unable to tell what the *minimal* example would be, as I am unable to reproduce the issue myself in lack of of the hardware in question. Driver and OS informationen added. It should be only a trivial, scattering shader, so I'm clueless why it could fail.

Comment: "Out of resource error." seems to me array data size bigger than allowed by that hardware. Check it at http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/

Comment: @Ripi2 That's at link time though, and it's unbounded buffers. There is no array data size in that context yet.